# Is it safe to destroy boost::asio timer from its handler or handler dtor?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In our product we have code that can be simplified to essentially this function:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <functional>

void DelayedCall(
    boost::asio::io_service& io,
    boost::asio::steady_timer::duration delay,
    std::function<void()> f)
{
    auto timer = std::make_shared<boost::asio::steady_timer>(io, delay);
    timer->async_wait(
        [timer, f](boost::system::error_code const&)
        {
            // Probably it's ok to do even this:
            //timer.reset();
            f();
        }
    );
}
```

Assume that `io` object has global lifetime for simplicity.

As you can see timer object will be destroyed in handler's destructor.

When this question come to my mind, I was beware of some references in timer to *executing* handler and vise versa. I know that timer destructor will call cancel on all async waiting handlers, but this is irrelevant as handler already executing and can not be canceled.

Now I think that timer object simply `post()`s handler to `io_service` when time comes, so both timer and handler become independent from each other. Nevertheless quick attempt to investigate asio source code failed, so I'm still not certain that our code is correct.

I didn't find anything relevant in documentation neither [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html) nor [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WaitableTimerService.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is safe and well-defined for all I/O objects.

---

Boost.Asio has taken efforts to support using `shared_ptr` to extend the lifetime of an object, such as a `steady_timer`, to be at least as long as a sequence of asynchronous operations by binding a `shared_ptr` to the object into the handlers.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html) notes:

> [...] permits programs to simplify their resource management by using `shared_ptr<>`. Where an object's lifetime is tied to the lifetime of a connection (or some other sequence of asynchronous operations), a `shared_ptr` to the object would be bound into the handlers for all asynchronous operations associated with it.

To support this, initiating functions accept handlers by-value, and Boost.Asio is responsibility for maintaining the validity of the handler.  The implementation may make copies of the handler, and all copies are guaranteed to be destroyed:

- immediately after the handler has been invoked
- the `io_service` is destroyed
- the `io_service::service` that owns the handler is shutdown via [`shutdown_service()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__service/shutdown_service.html)

The [requirements on asynchronous operations documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) states:

> Arguments to initiating functions will be treated as follows:
>
> — If the parameter is declared as a const reference or by-value, the program is not required to guarantee the validity of the argument after the initiating function completes. The implementation may make copies of the argument, and all copies will be destroyed no later than immediately after invocation of the handler.

Comment: I trust you, but your citations aren't relevant to my question. They all talks about an `io_service` object, not timers. I didn't found anything in timers documentation neither [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html), nor [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WaitableTimerService.html).

Comment: @magras Perhaps I have misunderstood the question.  The former citation was to accentuate that Asio has been developed to support the type of resource management your code is using.  Together, the linked material defines when handlers are destroyed, and in your case, this defines when `steady_timer` will be destroyed.

Comment: My bad. I tried to clarify question. Check edit if you still interested in it.

Comment: @magras I think I understand the concern.  When a handler is ready for execution (expiration or cancellation), it will be wrapped and scheduled for deferred execution as-if by `io_service.post()`. At that point, the handler is independent of any implicit associations to the I/O object. This behavior is defined in the requirements on asynchronous operations "when an asynchronous operation is complete" section.  It is also mentioned for the handler parameter on the [`async_wait()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html) operation.

Comment: Let's assume that timer wraps user provided handler in some wrapper before `post`ing it. This wrapper stores raw pointer to timer object to inform timer about execution completion. I didn't think that this assumption is true, but only after very thoughtful rereading I found contradiction with documentation: «The implementation will perform `asio_handler_deallocate(p, size, &h)`, where `p` is a pointer to the storage, to deallocate the storage prior to the invocation of the `handler via asio_handler_invoke`.» This proof is fragile, but I really appreciate your help Tanner.

Comment: @magras A handler is _not_ aware of the I/O object.  A `deadline_timer` knows its expiration time and has a list of pending handlers.  A `deadline_timer_service` has a queue of all `deadline_timer`s and knows the earliest expiration.  The `deadline_timer_service` schedules the reactor to wake up based on the earliest expiration across all timers.  When the reactor wakes, it removes all handlers from expired timers, wraps the handler with the appropriate `error_code`, and posts the handlers to the `io_service` for deferred invocation.

Comment: @magras The `asio_handler_*` hooks are used in the following flow: In the initiating function, allocate memory via `asio_handler_allocate`, and copy the user handler into some of the memory.  When the operation completes, use a copy of the user handle to create a bound handler that has automatic storage, then deallocate memory via `asio_handler_deallocate`. Invoke the bound handler via `asio_handler_invoke`.  Automatic storage allows for cleanup if the handler throws, and if the handler initiates a new operation, the previously allocated memory can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

The timer will be destroyed when the `shared_ptr` reference counter become 0 and this will happen when the closure which `shared_ptr` is a part of will be destroyed. So it is safe to use it in this particular way. However, note, if you change the way you pass your timer to lambda, for example by reference `[&timer]` or by moving `[timer = std::(move(timer))]` this code will crash because no `shared_ptr` reference be incremented on copying and the timer will be destroyed on your handler scope exit.

Comment: It is safe for a timer to be destroyed with outstanding wait operations.  The outstanding wait operations will be implicitly cancelled within the timer's destructor.  This allows for capturing-by-reference to be safe, but likely has undesirable effects.  On the other hand, capturing-by-move invokes undefined behavior due to the sequencing order between the lambda capture's side effects and `shared_ptr::operator->()`.

Comment: @Tanner, thanks, that's much cleaner. Later I'll post results of my asio source code investigation.